# how to push secondary menu just below the primary horizontal navbar?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-web-api, navbar

I am trying to place the secondary menu which dropdown while hovering on the listitem of the primary navbar, just below that item and, over any content just below the navbar.

But my secondary menu floats above the listitem and behind the adjoining listitem. Also its hiding behind the below lying content.

I tried this :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
        CodeBehind="Site2.master.cs" Inherits="abc.Site2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <link href="stylesheets/StyleSheet1.css" type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" />

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <style type="text/css">
            ul {
                list-style: none;
            }

            ul#pri.nav {
                margin-left: 0px;
                margin-top: 50px;
                z-index: -1;
                border-top-right-radius: 15px;
                border-top-left-radius: 15px;
                text-decoration: none;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: rgb(180, 221, 180);
            }

            ul.nav {
                height: 10px;
            }

            ul.nav li {
                float: left;
                margin-top: 0px;
                padding: 10px 13px;
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size: small;
                line-height: 15px;
                cursor: pointer;
                font-weight: 700;
            }

            ul.nav#pri li {
                margin-top: 0px;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 5px;
                font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
                color: #fff;
                width: 100px;
                height: 6px;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 20px;
                display: block;
                -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
                -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
                -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
                -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
                border-bottom-style: none;
                border-bottom-color: inherit;
                border-bottom-width: medium;
                background-color: #0fc15e;
                position: relative;
                bottom: 45px;
            }

            ul.nav#pri li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
            }

            ul.nav#pri li.active,
            ul.nav#pri li:hover ul.nav#sec {
                display: block;
                font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
                color: #a67cd5;
            }

            .nav#pri li:hover ul {
                color: #2b95b2;
            }

            ul.nav#sec {
                display: none;
            }

            ul.nav#sec li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 14px;
            }

            ul.nav#sec li:hover {
                font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #fff;
                background-color: #747171;
            }

            .auto-style2 {
                height: 550px;
            }

            .auto-style3 {
                height: 454px;
                margin-top: 40px;
            }

            .auto-style4 {
                height: 133px;
                margin-top: 81px;
            }

            .auto-style5 {
                margin-left: 57px;
            }

            .auto-style6 {
                width: 123px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body style="height: 600px">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style2">
            <div class="auto-style2">
                <div class="auto-style3">
                    <div style="margin-top :80px">
                        <div style="width:100%; float:left; margin-top: -20px;">
                            <div style="float:left; width:44%; text-align:justify; margin-left:20px; 
       margin-top:-20px;">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="40" Width="150" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ Logo.png" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <ul id="pri" class="nav" style="height: 10px; margin-top: 30px">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a href="AfterLogin.aspx">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="rubrics.aspx">Rubrics</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="CreateUser.aspx">Create User</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Reports</a>
                                <ul id="sec" class="nav" style="margin-left: 3px">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="a">a</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="b">b</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="c">c</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="auto-style6">
                                <a href="AdminMessaging.aspx">Messages</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="auto-style5">
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="logout" onclick="logout_Click">Sign Out</asp:LinkButton>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="p1" class="auto-style4">
            <div style="height:10px;"></div>
            <div style="color:#F5F5F5;text-align:center;">
                Copyright © xyz
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is whats happening :
[image]

How to resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the style of

```
`ul.nav#sec`
```

**TO:**

```
margin-left: -59px;
bottom: -4rem;
position: absolute;
z-index: 10;
```

```css
ul {
list-style: none;
}

ul#pri.nav {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top:50px;
  z-index: -1;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(180, 221, 180);

}

ul.nav {
  height: 10px;
}

ul.nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
  line-height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
}

ul.nav#pri li {
  margin-top: 0px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  height: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 15px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-bottom-color: inherit;
  border-bottom-width: medium;
  background-color: #0fc15e;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 45px;
}

ul.nav#pri li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

ul.nav#pri li.active,
ul.nav#pri li:hover ul.nav#sec {
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
  color: #a67cd5;
}

.nav#pri li:hover ul {
  color: #2b95b2;
}

ul.nav#sec {
display: none;
    margin-left: -59px;
    bottom: -4rem;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}


ul.nav#sec li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}

ul.nav#sec li:hover {
  font-family: 'Arial Rounded MT';
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #747171;
}

      .auto-style2 {
        height: 550px;
      }

      .auto-style3 {
        height: 454px;
        margin-top: 40px;
      }

      .auto-style4 {
        height: 133px;
        margin-top: 81px;
      }

      .auto-style5 {
        margin-left: 57px;
      }

      .auto-style6 {
        width: 123px;
      }
```

```html
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="auto-style2">
      <div class="auto-style2">
        <div class="auto-style3">

          <div style="margin-top :80px">
            <div style="width:100%; float:left; margin-top: -20px;">
              <div style="float:left; width:44%; text-align:justify; margin-left:20px; 
   margin-top:-20px;">

                <asp:Image ID="Image1" Height="40" Width="150" ImageAlign="Middle" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ Logo.png" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />

          <div>
            <ul id="pri" class="nav" style="height: 10px; margin-top: 30px">
              <li class="active"><a href="AfterLogin.aspx">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="rubrics.aspx">Rubrics</a>
                              <ul id="sec" class="nav">
                  <li><a href="a">a</a></li>
                  <li><a href="b">b</a></li>
                  <li><a href="c">c</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="CreateUser.aspx">Create User</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Reports</a>
                <ul id="sec" class="nav">
                  <li><a href="a">a</a></li>
                  <li><a href="b">b</a></li>
                  <li><a href="c">c</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="auto-style6"><a href="AdminMessaging.aspx">Messages</a></li>

              <li class="auto-style5">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" id="logout" onclick="logout_Click">Sign Out</asp:LinkButton>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </div>

          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">





          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
    <div id="p1" class="auto-style4">
      <div style="height:10px;"></div>

      <div style="color:#F5F5F5;text-align:center;">
        Copyright © xyz
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I wanted. Let me check if it does'nt hide behind the below content.

Comment: But text in some of the items is getting sliced off.

Comment: Do you mean the items inside the <li> ?

Comment: yes in the secondary menu. also there is an additional bar sorta thing .Plus when i move down the secmenu..the menu disappears. Basically the primary li should be active.

Comment: @Liamm12..could you also have a look at this issue..if you dont mind.

Comment: @AnitaMathew Yes sure please I need your full code the problem isn't in this code, as you see I fixed it